# Replace Subversion Folder and Retain History

Tags: svn, version-control, replace, history, directory

I have two development trees v3.3, and v3.4 in one SVN repository. They both contain a project called test-harness. However, the v3.4 developers have wrecked the test-harness so we need the test-harness from project in v3.3 to overwrite what we have in v3.4. I want to retain the history of change made to 3.4 test-harness as it has some interesting ideas.
I had thought of deleting the 3.4 test-harness folder, then just adding an exported copy of 3.3 test-harness into 3.4, but then I'd lose the v3.4 test-harness history . . .
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When removing the 3.4 folder and copying the 3.3 folder over it nothing is lost. That’s what subversion is there for. You can access the “old” version 3.4 by using a “peg revision”, i.e. use

```
svn ls path:/to/repository/version/3.4@<some old revision>
```

to take a look at what the path looked like at that old revision.

Comment: Are peg revisions the same as tags in tortoise svn?

Comment: I’ve never used TortoiseSVN. Tags are something different, though—even in subversion which does not really have tags. Check http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html for details on peg revisions.

Comment: Thanks, I never quite understood what peg revisions were for, but tonight I replaced something with history (like the op was contemplating), and then had to figure out how to see the old history too.  Peg revisions! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can delete all files in the 3.4 folder and then branch (or copy) V3.3 in that empty folder. Subversion will keep the entire history of the 3.4 folder anyway. I think the best thing would be to branch the current 3.4 Version into an alternative folder (e.g 3.4-broken should keep the history, too), delete the original folder and branch 3.3 into 3.4.

Comment: Why would I branch the 3.4 to an alternative folder when svn keeps the history anyway?

Comment: To make it easier to access it with some kind of repository browser.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it helps you:

Move a file or directory

```
svn move source destination
```

Renaming a file or directory:

```
svn rename oldname newname
```

[]'s,

And Past